# How to upgrade an old package in say Ubuntu 6.10 to what's available for 10.04? (i.e. openssh)

Tags: upgrade, apt, package-management

I would like to learn how to upgrade packages in older Ubuntu versions to what's available in current versions.

I assume there is always a manual way to do it, but is there something more automated such as using additional sources and the power of apt-get?

Thanks,
Nile

Answer (score 4):

The process is called backporting. There is (was) an official backports repository for 6.10 but it won't cover what you need.

6.10 went "end of life" over two and a half years ago. This means you're probably missing some serious patches that you need to stay secure. Is there a reason you're not upgrading the whole system?

Upgrading from such an old non-LTS release to current might take a very, very long time. You're probably in a position where a fresh install of the latest is the best plan of action.

But at this point, short of finding a PPA (are they even compatible with 6.10?), you'll need to download the source of whatever you want and compile it yourself.

Comment: I used 6.10 to start with b/c the version had very good documentation for a particular package I was interested in using. But later the use of the system has been extended to more things, hence the security concerns.